# Error building stubs with JAX-WS: "Two declarations cause a collision..."

Tags: xml, jax-ws

I am trying to use JAX-WS on a WSDL file form a 3rd party, but I get an error (details below). Can anybody help me figure out what goes wrong, and how to fix it?

**EDIT:** I can make it compile, but I don't like the fix, and I especially don't like that I don't understand the fix. See below.

```
[WARNING] src-resolve.4.2: Error resolving component 'q1:CorrectRequest'. It was detected that 'q1:CorrectRequest' is in namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Satori.Infuse.Single', but components from this namespace are not referenceable from schema document 'file:/Users/itunesuser/git/listiq/iac-extension/src/main/resources/com/satorisoftware/ws/infuseiac/intladdresscorrection/intladdresscorrection.wsdl#types?schema1'. If this is the incorrect namespace, perhaps the prefix of 'q1:CorrectRequest' needs to be changed. If this is the correct namespace, then an appropriate 'import' tag should be added to 'file:/Users/itunesuser/git/listiq/iac-extension/src/main/resources/com/satorisoftware/ws/infuseiac/intladdresscorrection/intladdresscorrection.wsdl#types?schema1'.
  line 98 of file:/Users/itunesuser/git/listiq/iac-extension/src/main/resources/com/satorisoftware/ws/infuseiac/intladdresscorrection/intladdresscorrection.wsdl#types?schema1

[ERROR] Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class.
  line 356 of file:/Users/itunesuser/git/listiq/iac-extension/src/main/resources/com/satorisoftware/ws/infuseiac/intladdresscorrection/intladdresscorrection.wsdl

[ERROR] (Related to above error) This is the other declaration.   
  line 98 of file:/Users/itunesuser/git/listiq/iac-extension/src/main/resources/com/satorisoftware/ws/infuseiac/intladdresscorrection/intladdresscorrection.wsdl
```

Here's the occurrence at line 98

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:ser="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"
    elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="infuse.satorisoftware.com/2012/08">
    <xsd:element name="Correct">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element
                    xmlns:q1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Satori.Infuse.Single"
                    minOccurs="0" name="request" nillable="true" type="q1:CorrectRequest" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    (MORE xsd ELEMENTS)

</xsd:schema>
```

Here's the occurrence at line 356

```
<xsd:schema
    xmlns:tns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Satori.Infuse.Single"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    targetNamespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Satori.Infuse.Single">
    <xsd:complexType name="CorrectRequest">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Client" nillable="true"
                type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element xmlns:q5="infuse.satorisoftware.com/2012/08"
                minOccurs="0" name="Input" nillable="true" type="q5:RecordBlock" />
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="OutputFields"
                nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfInfuseField" />
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="ReferenceString"
                nillable="true" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element xmlns:q6="infuse.satorisoftware.com/2012/08"
                minOccurs="0" name="Settings" type="q6:Settings" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:element name="CorrectRequest" nillable="true" 
        type="tns:CorrectRequest" />

    (MORE xsd ELEMENTS)

</xsd:schema>
```

**EDIT:** If I change the name of the element, it compiles, but I would like to find a better fix, and to understand why this fix works.

```
    <xsd:element name="CorrectRequestElement" nillable="true" 
        type="tns:CorrectRequest" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So: The warning is really not that interesting. What matters is the errors.

The errors try to tell us this:

> "Hi! I'm JAXB, and I can't figure out how to name the Java classes I'm
>   generating from the WSDL without getting name conflicts. Herp! Derp!"

The solution is to use a bindings file, which is basically a way to annotate (or patch) the WSDL file with directives that are relevant for JAXB.

[Here's a nice end-to-end example with lots of background information.](http://www.jroller.com/gmazza/entry/enhancing_jaxb_artifacts)

In my particular case I needed to do two things:

1. Make a bindings file
2. Make changes to my POM so the bindings file was used in the WSDL processing phase

**Bindings file:**

My goal here is to tell JAXB that I want it to use a different name for the Java class for this bit of the WSDL file:

```
<xsd:element name="CorrectRequest" nillable="true" 
        type="tns:CorrectRequest" />
```

This will do the trick:

```
<bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.1"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <bindings schemaLocation="../resources/com/satorisoftware/ws/infuseiac/intladdresscorrection/intladdresscorrection.wsdl#types?schema3" version="1.0">
        <schemaBindings>
            <package name="com.satorisoftware.ws.infuseiac-intladdresscorrection" />
        </schemaBindings>

        <!-- rename the value element -->
        <bindings node="//xsd:element[@name='CorrectRequest']">
                <class name="CorrectRequestElement" />
        </bindings>
    </bindings>
</bindings>
```

**Updating the POM:**

I added a `bindingsFiles` entry to the relevant build phase:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.12</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>import-iac-wsdl</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsimport</goal>
            </goals>
            <inherited>false</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <packageName>com.satorisoftware.ws.infuseiac.intladdresscorrection</packageName>
                <wsdlLocation>com/satorisoftware/ws/infuseiac/intladdresscorrection/intladdresscorrection.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
                <staleFile>${project.build.directory}/jaxws/stale/wsdl.intladdresscorrection.done</staleFile>
                <sourceDestDir>${project.build.directory}/generated/jaxws-infuseiac-intladdresscorrection</sourceDestDir>
                <wsdlDirectory>src/main/resources/com/satorisoftware/ws/infuseiac/intladdresscorrection</wsdlDirectory>
                <bindingFiles>
                    <!-- See http://www.jroller.com/gmazza/entry/enhancing_jaxb_artifacts#BindingFile 
                    for an end-to-end-example of doing bindings files for WSDL files. -->
                    <bindingFile>${basedir}/src/main/bindings/bindings-intladdresscorrection.xjb</bindingFile>
                </bindingFiles>
                <!-- <wsdlUrls> <value>https://infuseiac.satorisoftware.com/wsdl/IntlAddressCorrection.2012.12.wsdl</value> 
                    </wsdlUrls> -->

                <!-- Generate JAX-WS 2.0 compatible stubs -->
                <target>2.0</target>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```